# jQuery slideToggle reverse effect on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I made a custom menu on Wordpress with jQuery slideToggle to toggle dropdown on hover. The code is relatively simple and everything works fine.

But I discovered when I refresh the page while moving the cursor between two menu items that have dropdown menus the slideToggle effect basically reverses on one of them. Slides away when I move my cursor on it and comes back when I move the cursor away from the menu.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".has-mega-menu").has('.sub-menu').children('.sub-menu').hide();
      jQuery('.has-mega-menu').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).has('.sub-menu').children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="has-mega-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-28">
      <a href="shop-link">Shop</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="height: 222px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="mega-menu-column menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-42"><a href="#">TEST</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41">
              <a href="#">Test Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36">
              <a href="Shop-link">Test Item 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-43" class="mega-menu-column menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-43">
          <a href="#">TEST 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44">
              <a href="#">Test Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45">
              <a href="#">Test Item 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-46" class="mega-menu-column menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-46">
          <a href="#">TEST 3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47">
              <a href="#">Test Item 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not exactly sure what was happening. Something with the order getting messed up with the toggle. But the way I fixed it was having slidedown and slideup separately. And I also added z-index's so the animation of sliding is constant.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.has-mega-menu > .sub-menu').hide();
    jQuery('.has-mega-menu').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).has('.sub-menu').children('.sub-menu').stop().slideDown(250);
        jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').css('z-index', '2')
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).has('.sub-menu').children('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp(250);
        jQuery(this).children('.sub-menu').css('z-index', '1')
    });
});
```